# Pandas - Parse time data with and without milliseconds

Tags: python, pandas

How do you parse time data if the time is in the format `2007-08-06T18:11:44.688Z`, but treats no milliseconds as `2007-08-06T18:11:44Z`?

`pd.to_datetime(x.split('Z')[0], errors='coerce', format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')` to remove remove the Zulu marker fails due to the `.` being missing sometimes.

`pd.to_datetime(x.split('.')[0], errors='coerce', format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')` to remove the milliseconds fails due to the `.` being missing sometimes.

`pd.to_datetime(x.split('.|Z')[0], errors='coerce', format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')` fails sometimes too, even though it looks like it should split on both cases witt the 0 member being the part we want and thus always give a valid time in seconds.

Comment: The very awkward `pd.to_datetime(x.split('.')[0].split('Z')[0],format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')` seems to work, but the doubling of the split operation increases runtime.

Comment: in pandas 0.18.1 `pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2007-08-06T18:11:44.688Z']))` returns: `0   2007-08-06 18:11:44.688`, `dtype: datetime64[ns]`. What pandas version are you using?

Comment: 0.16.2 (from Python x,y)

Comment: what does `pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2007-08-06T18:11:44.688Z']))` return in pandas 0.16.2?

Comment: Specifying format specifically to try to get the data in a form Matplotlib can handle (matplotlib can't deal with `np.datetime64[ns]`, which is the default behavior for pandas).

Comment: @MaxU It does work, but returns are forced to `np.datetime64[ns]`, which I personally don't understand why Pandas uses if Matplotlib can't.

Comment: @Elliot  what version of matplotlib are you using? Can you upgrade these packages?

Comment: @Elliot, `datetime64[ns]` - is a default pandas datetime dtype

Comment: @MaxU I know, but since everything I need to do involves plotting things, having the times in a format matpltlib cannot handle makes them worthless.

Comment: @Merlin I cannot change these versions. Matplotlib is 1.4.3.

Comment: then it's a matplotlib issue, not pandas. Please open a new question with a small sample data set and a short description what do you want to plot and how

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can simply use `pd.to_datetime(df_column_or_series)` without specifying the `format` parameter should properly parse both your datetime formats

having or not having `Zulu` marker, doesn't change anything - you will have the same dtype after your string is converted to pandas datetime dtype:

```
In [366]: pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2007-08-06T18:11:44.688Z'])).dtypes
Out[366]: dtype('<M8[ns]')

In [367]: pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2007-08-06T18:11:44.688'])).dtypes
Out[367]: dtype('<M8[ns]')

In [368]: pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2007-08-06T18:11:44'])).dtypes
Out[368]: dtype('<M8[ns]')

In [369]: pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2007-08-06'])).dtypes
Out[369]: dtype('<M8[ns]')

In [371]: pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2007-08-06T18:11:44.688']), format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').dtypes
Out[371]: dtype('<M8[ns]')
```